# All of a sudden not possible to run Kotlin tests in IntelliJ anymore

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a big Kotlin project with about 2500 unit tests written for KotlinTest. The project is a gradle project and I am able to run all the tests from a Gradle task, but normally I run them from the editor. I was able to run individual tests from the editor by clicking the Run Icon.

Yesterday this worked fine, today it doesn't. Nothing changed. Absolutely nothing. When I hover on the icon it says "Nothing Here". When I add a main function I can execute the main function, but not the tests. The test folder is marked as Test Sources Root.

This is extremely frustrating, because for every time I change something I want to test an individual Unit test and not having to test the 2500 others....

IntelliJ is up to date. Kotlin plugin is the latest.

EDIT:
I found out that it works if I add a `fun main(args: Array<String>)` to the top of the file. Weird!?

Comment: No ideas on why it's not working. I'd dig into KotlinTest and what it uses to run the tests. Is it JUnit4 or Unit Jupiter based? Perhaps something changed in the IDE. Or try clearing caches and restarting IntelliJ. Perhaps it messed something up in an index. Also, Gradle CLI supports filtering tests using `--tests` parameter so if nothing else, can run individual tests from CLI. `-- tests "*MyTest*"` or `--tests "*MyTest.verifySomeFunction*"` is the idea

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling your kotlin plugin?

Comment: What version of kotlintest?

Comment: I've just created a very similar question - could be a duplicate by maybe not? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396253/running-tests-suddenly-started-failing-silently-in-a-single-java-project

Comment: The same problem with Intellij Idea 2019.1: "Nothing here" sign appears when clicking "Run Test" green triangle on the left side to the method's name

Comment: Switched back to 2018.3.6 - still experienced this problem.
Than switched to 2018.2.8 - and tests are running great again!

Comment: Yeah, but you are running an old version now...

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if I put everything inside the class, then it works. In other words, no functions or constants or anything is outside the class, at the file level.