# Running tests suddenly started failing silently in a single Java project

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project that I've been working on for a few weeks with no problems. I've made no changes at all since it was working yesterday morning, but since yesterday afternoon running any test in just that project fails silently.

I see (or rather, don't see) the same thing regardless of how I run a test - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, right-clicking in the code view or in the project view and choosing 'Run ...Test', or clicking the 'Play' button in the top-right corner on a previously-working test. Interestingly, in this last case, I only had one chance to do it - the 'Play' button is now greyed-out, even if I create a new run configuration. The same is true for running, debugging and 'run with coverage'.

When I run a test, I get no feedback whatsoever, the test doesn't run, nothing appears in the status bar or the idea.log file.

This is in a multi-module Maven project, and I see the same for all tests in all submodules of that project. I am running 2018.1.6 (Ultimate Edition) on Windows 7. I updated to 2018.1.6 a couple of days ago, but it's been working fine since then.

The tests in all my other projects work perfectly well.

I've restarted IntelliJ, invalidating the caches, I've re-imported the project, and even re-cloned it and created a new copy of it from scratch. I've restarted my machine.

A colleague had experienced the same problem in a different project (that project works fine for me) with 2018.1.5 a few days ago, and has resolved it by completely uninstalling IntelliJ and reinstalling 2018.1.4. I'd rather not resort to that if possible.

Comment: Seems like maybe this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703079/all-of-a-sudden-not-possible-to-run-kotlin-tests-in-intellij-anymore, but I'm not sure how to apply the equivalent to the solution mentioned in his edit to a Java project.

Comment: After updating to 2018.1.6 and now IntelliJ is unable to find test resources for me..

Comment: Not an answer, but I've just upgraded to version 2018.2, and the problem has gone away.

Comment: The same problem with Intellij Idea 2019.1: "Nothing here" sign appears when clicking "Run Test" green triangle on the left side to the method's name